# What is the logic behind glGetActiveUniformBlockParam of GL_UNIFORM_BLOCK_DATA_SIZE?

Tags: opengl, glsl

My shader source is this one :

```
#version 330

uniform mat4 camera;

struct S {
  vec2 v;
  mat2 m;
};

layout(std140) uniform SS {
 S s[2];
};

in vec2 v;

void main () {
  gl_Position = camera * vec4(v.x + s[0].m[0][0], v.y, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

When I ask how big is my uniform block, GL answers `96`. But if I assume that a `mat2` is 4 floats, a `vec2` is 2 floats and I have two of them, and that a `float` is 4 bytes, then:

```
(4 + 2) * 2 * 4 = 48
```

I find `48` bytes… Why so much ?

Maybe it comes from alignement of my structs to 4 bytes. Let's add 2 bytes of padding to account for alignment, after my `vec2`:

```
(4 + 2 + 2) * 2 * 4 = 64
```

This is `64`, *not* `96`. So where am I wrong? In fact I'm quite sure my floats are 4 bytes, since I can retrieve them when they follow each other…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is normal for the `std140` layout. To understand why, you need to read up on the alignment rules outlined below:

#### [OpenGL 4.4 Core Profile Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) - 7.6.2.2 Standard Uniform Block Layout - pp. 131

> Rule (4):
>
> > If the member is an array of scalars or vectors, the base alignment and array stride are set to match the base alignment of a single array element, according to rules **(1)**, **(2)**, and **(3)**, and ***rounded up to the base alignment of a `vec4`***. The array may have padding at the end; the base offset of the member following the array is rounded up to the next multiple of the base alignment.
>
> Rule (5):
>
> > If the member is a column-major matrix with **C** columns and **R** rows, the matrix is stored identically to an array of **C** column vectors with **R** components each, according to rule **(4)**.

---

I have re-written your data structure to indicate how it looks from the perspective of `std140` alignment:

```c
struct S {
  vec2 v;
  vec2 v_padding;  // NEW (satisfies rule 4 -- mat2 has base alignment 4N)

  //mat2 m;        // ORIGINAL (re-written below for alignment -- see rule 5)

  vec2 m0;
  vec2 m0_padding; // NEW (satisfies rule 4 -- column vectors are aligned to 4N)
  vec2 m1;
  vec2 m1_padding; // NEW (satisfies rule 4 -- column vectors are aligned to 4N)
};
```

- `vec2 v` -> 2N + 2N
- `mat2 m` -> 2N + 2N + 2N + 2N

Total Struct Size (in machine units): 4N + 8N = 12N

#### Size (in bytes) for array: `S s [2]`:

12N * 2 = 24N * 4/N = **96**

---

Your biggest problem here is the use of a `mat` type.

Matrices are treated as arrays of vectors, which adds extra alignment oddities. In some cases you can get around these oddities by using row-major matrices, but since this is a square matrix that will not help any.

Instead of a `mat2`, I would suggest you pack your data into a `vec4`.

```c
struct S {
  vec2 v; // 2N + 2N (padding)
  vec4 m; // 4N
};        // 8N
```

2N + 2N + 4N = 8N * 2 * 4/N = ***64 bytes***

You can write some extra code to unpack the `vec4` into a `mat2` variable if you really need a `mat2` in your shader.

Comment: I read the 3.3 core spec with the 10 alignment rules and was about to answer myself, but your answer is better :) ty